# sql - insert new row where field equals another value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Wherever CODE="BB", i want to insert a new row with all the same row/column data just change the CODE to "XX".

For example:

**Current Table:**

```
ID |    CODE  | Name
---+----------+---------
 1 |    AA    | Tom
 2 |    BB    | Mary
 3 |    AA    | John
 4 |    CC    | Carlos
 5 |    CC    | Mario
 6 |    BB    | Steve
 7 |    AA    | Pablo
```

**Same After SQL statement executed:**

```
ID |    CODE  | Name
---+----------+---------
 1 |    AA    | Tom
 2 |    BB    | Mary
 3 |    AA    | John
 4 |    CC    | Carlos
 5 |    CC    | Mario
 6 |    BB    | Steve
 7 |    AA    | Pablo
 8 |    XX    | Mary
 9 |    XX    | Steve
```

**Can this be done in a SQL statement?** rather than do what i was going to do which was create a script to loop through each record checking for "BB" and inserting a new row based on it's values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code includes a check to make sure an 'XX' version doesn't already exist.

```
INSERT INTO CurrentTable
    (CODE, Name)
    SELECT 'XX', ct1.Name
        FROM CurrentTable ct1
        WHERE ct1.CODE = 'BB'
            AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                               FROM CurrentTable ct2
                               WHERE ct1.name = ct2.name
                                   AND ct2.CODE = 'XX')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID is an IDENTITY column:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Code, Name)
SELECT ('XX', Name) FROM myTable 
WHERE CODE ='BB'
```

(Not rerunnable...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you generate id's but this is how it's working:

```
insert into my_table 
select new_id() as id, 'xx' as Code, Name 
from my_table 
where Code='BB'
```